# var organisations []Organisation creates an array of Organisation. But how may "container/list" create a list of Organisation (and not of anything?)

Tags: arrays, list, go

### First choice: using slice

```golang
var organisations []*Organisation

for _, org := range ... { // 2 to 10 000 items expected
    organisations = append(organisations, org)
}
```

- I have strong typing,

### Second choice: using `container/list`

```golang
import "container/list"

organisations := list.New()

for _, org := range ... {
    organisations.MoveToBack(org) // Refused: cannot use type *Organisation as the type *Element
}
```

- it has no typing at all. If I send this list to another function, as it is, the receiver won't trust its content, as from its declaration it is filled with anything.

How may I declare a list of `Organisation`? Like I can create an array of them?

May attempt is refused, and I don't understand why.

Comment: "but won't this be slow?" No. Why should it? "I expect it to be faster." Why? On what ground? Based on what reasoning. And what is "fast" and "slow" and why does it matter for that type of code?

Comment: I remove the side question about the speed to allow focusing on the the main question: how to get a list of typed objects from `container/list`?

Comment: You can create a generic linked list implementation with type parameters if you want. No one has made one for the std library (if there even will be one accepted, 3rd party implementations work just fine) because linked lists are rarely used.

Comment: "how to get a list of typed objects from container/list" You cannot. That's why nobody uses container list _unless_ a list is _the_ right DS for that task. With generics you now can write your own typesafe generc list container, but that's not with container/list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think using slices would be slow? Have you measured?

Slice insertion, especially if you pre-allocate the slice, is constant-time:

```
organizations:=make([]*Organization,0,len(...))
```

After this, each slice-append is simply setting a value in an array.

Even if you do not pre-allocate it, the slice will be dynamically resized and copied as necessary, but not for each element.

If you use a list, you'll lose random access, but you can efficiently insert anywhere in the list in constant time.

So, pick the solution based on how you're planning to use it after construction.

Comment: Even if you do not preallocate and the slice is reallocated on append, the amortized cost is still `O(1)`, so even that isn't a big deal in most cases. Yes, there's a reason linked lists are hardly ever used, arrays tend to outperform them even when random insertion is needed, because you can win so much back with data locality.